# Conflicting types em struct

Tags: c, struct

Olá. Estou aprendendo a implementar um código com tipos abstratos, mas ele está dando conflicting error para o tipo 'Data'. Qual poderia ser o problema? Não enxerguei problema de sintaxe, pelo menos.

arquivo header:

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

typedef struct data *Data;

Data * criaData (unsigned int dia, unsigned int mes, unsigned int ano);
Data * copiaData (Data d);
void liberaData (Data * d);
...
```

data.c (onde está dando os problemas):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define FEVEREIRO -1
#define MENOR -1
#define MAIOR 1
#define IGUAL 0

typedef struct data {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} Data;

Data * criaData (unsigned int dia, unsigned int mes, unsigned int ano) {
    Data *d = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    if (!d)
        return d;
    else {
        d->dia = dia;
        d->mes = mes;
        d->ano = ano;
        return d;
    }

}
...
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"

int main(void)
{
    int opcao = 1;
    unsigned int dias, dia, mes, ano;
    Data d, cpy, d1, d2;
    char *formato;
    while (opcao)
    {
        textttmain();
        switch (opcao)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Por favor, digite a data no formato ddmmaaaa: ");
            scanf("%2d%2d%4d", &dia, &mes, &ano);
            d = *criaData(dia, mes, ano);
...
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Construindo o código original no VS aparece o seguinte erro:

1. **'Data': 'data' differs in levels of indirection from 'data * '**

Nota-se que em `data.h` foi declarado `typedef struct data* Data` enquanto em `data.c` foi declarado `typedef struct data {...} Data`. Essas declarações entram em conflito, afinal quem é `Data`? É esse o aviso: `Data` é `struct data` ou `struct data *`? Esse erro é resolvido removendo o `*` de `typedef struct data* Data`. Entretanto, corrigido isso e recompilando aparecem outros 3 erros.

2. **'d' uses undefined struct 'data'** (esse erro se repete para as outras variáveis da linha `Data d, cpy, d1, d2;`)
3. **'=': cannot convert from 'Data' to 'int'** (em referência à linha `d = *criaData(dia, mes, ano);` )
4. **incomplete type is not allowed** (em referência à linha `d = *criaData(dia, mes, ano);`)

No fundo esses 3 erros possuem a mesma causa. Quando é declarado `Data d, cpy, d1, d2` em `main.c`, o compilador não sabe qual o espaço de memória que ele deve alocar porque ele desconhece a estrutura, que está `data.c` e não é incluída em `main.c`. Se o tamanho do tipo é desconhecido ele é um `incomplete type`. Uma possibilidade é deslocar para `data.h` a própria estrutura: `typedef struct data {...} Data`. Agora, `main.c` é capaz de ver a estrutura, uma vez que ela está no header, que é incluído em `main.c`. Com isso, a instrução corrigida do erro (1) `typedef struct data Data` é redundante e pode ser eliminada:.

No final o código é estruturado da seguinte forma:

**data.h**

```
#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H

typedef struct data {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} Data;

Data* criaData(unsigned int dia, unsigned int mes, unsigned int ano);

#endif
```

**data.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"

Data* criaData(unsigned int dia, unsigned int mes, unsigned int ano) {
    Data* d = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    if (!d)
        return d;
    else {
        d->dia = dia;
        d->mes = mes;
        d->ano = ano;
        return d;
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "data.h"

int main(void)
{
    int opcao = 1;
    unsigned int dias, dia, mes, ano;
    Data d, cpy, d1, d2;
    char* formato;
    while (opcao)
    {       
        switch (opcao)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Por favor, digite a data no formato ddmmaaaa: ");
            scanf("%2d%2d%4d", &dia, &mes, &ano);
            d = *criaData(dia, mes, ano);
        }
    }
}
```